# "opencv2/opencv.hpp": No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've been trying to use the library of opencv in a C++ project in Visual Studio 2017, but I've been dealing with an error I don't know how to solve it.

I am trying to do a simple #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> but I have always the same error, and is that the file is not found

In order to do this I have modified de VC++ directories (first image) and the linker  (second image).
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE9v6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE9v6.png).

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this silly question.
Thank you.

Comment: Where did you put these files? Did you edit your `c/c++->General->Additional Include Directories` setting for each configuration you use in each project that needs to use opencv?

Comment: @drescherjm It seems that this problem is solved. But now I have another problems with external symbols. But thank you for answering too soon!

Comment: ***problems with external symbols*** You need to link using `Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`

Comment: Yes I did that before, i added "opencv_world455d.lib" for the debug configuration, but I don't know why when I try to use "Mat" class it gives me an LNK2019 error.

Comment: does the folder opencv2 exist? This seems a simple path error. I suggest you to check the include path in your project properties and check the path on your system.

Comment: Hi @Massimo! Yes, it does exist, the include path is the following: *C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include*, where in this path is the opencv2 folder.

Comment: Yes, you need to add this path to project properties. You need to click on project properties -->C/C++-->General, then add it to Additional Include Directories.

Comment: is the path present in C++->general>additional include directory ?